# Arduino RBBB - Device not accepting address

Tags: arduino-uno

I recently purchases and make a Arduino RBBB with a BUB II from Modern Device. I ordered the package found [HERE](http://moderndevice.com/product/rbbb-bundle/). I built everything according to the instructions, but when I connect it to my laptop (running Ubuntu 14.10), I get the following in dmesg

```
[63415.213391] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 63 using xhci_hcd
[63415.381403] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[63415.485225] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Setup ERROR: setup context command for slot 26.
[63415.485240] usb 3-1: hub failed to enable device, error -22
[63415.597236] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 64 using xhci_hcd
[63415.709154] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[63415.813102] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Setup ERROR: setup context command for slot 27.
[63415.813116] usb 3-1: hub failed to enable device, error -22
[63415.925108] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 65 using xhci_hcd
[63415.925270] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[63416.129120] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[63416.332902] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 65, error -71
[63416.444973] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 66 using xhci_hcd
[63416.445174] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[63416.649008] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[63416.852734] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 66, error -71
[63416.852813] usb usb3-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

It is repeatable every time I insert. lsusb does not register it. I have read that I should switch out the cable, but it is brand new (and I don't have another to test with. I was wondering if there is something evidently wrong with my circuitry. I posted pictures

[image: Top Down]
[image: Side]
[image: Bottom]
[image: Side]

Comment: Have you tried another port? Another computer? Another serial adapter?

Comment: I tried another computer and switching USB ports on my laptop, same error. I don't have another BUB II, but tomorrow, I am going to go to a lab on campus to use the oscilloscope to check the BUB II I/O. I will also try another cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Here is how I did it.

First, I tried connecting just the BUB II to via the USB. Same error, thus I ruled out the Arduino RBBB as the source. I then decided that perhaps it was the voltage jumpers (black things on the pins sticking out in the first picture). After removing them, it works under dmesg, yielding the below.

```
[  214.044563] ftdi_sio 3-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[  214.044687] usb 3-1: Detected FT232RL
[  214.044696] usb 3-1: Number of endpoints 2
[  214.044704] usb 3-1: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[  214.044712] usb 3-1: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[  214.044718] usb 3-1: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[  214.045209] usb 3-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Thus I wanted to put them back on so I wouldn't lose them. I proceeded to try various combinations till it worked. Ultimately, I ended with 5V for VOUT and VL for LGLV. If that is a bad idea, someone please comment, but it works.

May this help someone else.

Comment: Since you fixed it, I upvoted it. It would be good to accept your own answer too, so this becomes the "accepted" answer to your issue.